# Multiprocessing with a fixed parameter for each cores

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I'd like to run a python multiprocess and I think I understand the basic pool, pool.apply_async and process. However, is there a way to run pool.apply_async with fixed parameters each core? Like having 4 people working for you to cut papers and each of them has a scissor, but they won't share their scissors with each other.

I think using pool.apply_async(func, arg) will distribute your load to the cores, however, would it be possible for each cores to hold a fixed argument which can be received by func as a parameter (i'm guessing it's not gonna be in arg because arg is just normal parameter)?

Comment: `apply_async` takes a sequence, but its value could be the same for everyone. If I wanted to use 42 a dozen times I could `pool.apply_async(forty_two_handler, (42 for _ in range(12)))`. Is that what you mean?

Comment: I want to attach a parameter to each of the 4 cores so that when that core is being used, the function takes that parameter

Answer (score 0):

`Pool` isn't setup to parameterize each worker process individually. But you can pass a generic initializer to each process so as long as you can figure out a way for that process to do something unique (perhaps lock, read and delete a file), then you can hack something together. Operating system level pipes and message queues are interesting, but I tried a Manager.Queue and it seemed to do the trick.

```
import multiprocessing as mp
import os
import time

def _pool_init(q):
    global unique_thing
    unique_thing = q.get()
    print("process {} unique {}".format(os.getpid(), unique_thing))

def _pool_worker(param):
    time.sleep(.1) # work really hard
    return "{}: {}".format(unique_thing, param)

def test():
    # distribute unique things to the processes running the pool
    unique_things = [1,2,3,4]
    init_q = mp.Manager().Queue()
    for u in unique_things:
        init_q.put(u)
    pool = mp.Pool(len(unique_things), initializer=_pool_init, initargs=(init_q,))
    for result in pool.map(_pool_worker, 'ABCDEFG'):
        print(result)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    if len(sys.argv) == 2:
        mp.set_start_method(sys.argv[1]) # "spawn" windows style or "fork" linux style
    test()
```